# Finding lowest cost for permutations of objects; how to overcome memory issues?

Tags: java, algorithm, memory, permutation

I'm not sure "permutation" is exactly the right word, but the scenario is that I have a `List` of ~40 `Objects`. Each different `Object` has a different `value` and `cost`.

Say my objects contain a `value` between 1 and 5. I am trying to combine a list of objects which exceed some given `targetValue`, find the combination with the lowest total `cost`, and return that combination. This combination could potentially contain many duplicates of one of the Objects in the `List`.

For an example, if my list of objects were { a, b, c, d }; the output *could* be { a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a }. However, note that **order also matters**. { a, a, b } may have a different total value than { a, b, a }

Currently, I've been trying to brute force the solution. However, with 40! combinations, I am running out of memory while keeping track of all the different "permutations".

I still prefer to run through every combination for accuracy, increased time to perform the calculation is not a problem, but as I said before, the biggest problem is memory.

Current code: (*incompleteList starts with a beginning Object*)

```
while (incompleteList.size() > 0)
{
    Container container = incompleteList.get(0);
    for (myObject o : objectList)
    {
        Container newAdditionContainer = new Container(container);//copies the list of objects into a new container
        newAdditionContainer.addMyObject(o);
        if (newAdditionContainer.getTotalValue()) < targetValue)
        {
            incompleteList.add(newAdditionContainer);
        } else {
            completeList.add(newAdditionContainer);
        }
    }
    incompleteList.remove(container);
} //code then loops through completeList and grabs the container with the cheapest cost, 
//but in actuality that code hasn't been able to run yet.
```

I'm pretty sure the above could work, if it were able to complete (but it cant due to memory); How can I change the algorithm to try and get the lowest cost and stay within memory limits?

Comment: Apologies for the pre-mature submit; i assume thats what the downvote was for?

Comment: I think the task is not very clear. How is the total `cost` and `value` calculated when the order matters? Why is the `List` a `List<Object>` when you specify that each object has a `cost` and `value`. Seems like you could invent an `interface` to represent these `Objects` (btw i didn't downvote)

Comment: I apologize, i think the equations going into the calculations are beyond the scope of the question and just serve to complicate matters. The `Container` class can calculate the value of its contained Objects, and the `cost` is simply added between all Objects, but is unknown until runtime.

Comment: So the `cost` and `value` are properties of a permutation of `Object`s and not the `Object` itself? Do all permutations have a fixed length?

Comment: no fixed length; they just (eventually) always meet and exceed "targetValue", by which I mean the value cannot begin to decrease or stay the same with additional Objects added on; it always increases

Comment: But adding more elements always increases both `cost` and `value`?

Comment: Yes, but due to differing costs; { a, b } may cost more and give same value as { a, c, c, d, f }. Though you could add anything onto the end of { a, b } and know both cost and value will increase, even if just slightly.

Comment: @DoubleDouble - *increased time to perform the calculation is not a problem, but as I said before, the biggest problem is memory*. Are you positive about that? Are you aware that 40! is something like 8*10^47? Assume you can calculate **1 trillion combinations per second** (which is absolutely unrealistic). Did you know that would mean about 2.6*10^28 YEARS to complete? The universe is only ~13.8*10^9 years. The question is just insane. You simply cannot use brute force for this problem with current (and foreseeable future) technology!

Comment: @DoubleDouble - another way to put it: solving the problem the way you describe is a much more computationally expensive problem than brute forcing an AES-128 key...

Comment: @BrunoReis I thought it would be best to focus this question on memory usage, since I couldn't wrap my head around it, and make a separate question for speed if I couldn't find a workable heuristic myself; but if you know one off the top of your head i'd be interested in hearing it.

Comment: Your problem is basically an optimization problem: "given a function f: X->R (where X is the input space of your problem), find x \in X such that f(x) is the minimum value possible for f". There are a whole lot of techniques to solve this, including brute force. For "large" problem (such as yours), brute force doesn't work.

Comment: If you have a "reasonable" maximum size of the input vector, it feels like you'd be able to describe the problem as a linear problem (ie, minimize cost(x) with value(x) >= targetValue, where cost(x) and value(x) are linear functions of a fixed-sized vector x; the difficulty here would be to define the structure of this fixed-sized vector x). If you can do that, then there are many "linear programming" techniques to solve that kind of problem. I would investigate that option!

Comment: These are "permutations with repetition". The formula for that doesn't have a factorial. It's just n to the power of r, where n is the number of items in the list and r is how many you are going to select. If your list is {a, b, c, d} then n = 4, and the number of lists like { a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a } with 10 elements will be 4^10

Answer (score 2):

Build a `PermIterator` which is intialized with your `List` of `Object`s and a desired `permutation length`. `Iterate` this `Iterator` beginning with `length` 1 until for a complete `iteration` with the same `length` all `permutations` exceed the desired `value`. Always store only the actual `permutation` and the current best `permutation`, which exceeds the desired value and has the lowest cost, independent of `permutation length`.
This way you avoid storing all the `permutations` in `List`s and going out of memory. Obviously with 40 `Object`s this can still take quite long.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty common to run out of memory if you attempt to load all the possible data before doing anything with it. This is also a problem when reading large files.

A simple solution is to not store all the values if there is many of them but rather process them as you crate them.

I suggest having a callback or lambda you call each time you create a new permutation. This way you don't need to store them.

Note with 40! Permutations you are likely to run out of time. At one per micro second it will take 2.5e34 years. Longer than the planet has left.